# What is a monodromy representation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces, monodromy

I'm currently studying the Global Torelli Theorem for K3 surfaces and I encountered the following section in Huybrechts book.

> If $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow S$ is a smooth proper morphism over a connected base $S$ with $X=\mathcal{X}_t$ for some fixed $t \in S$, then the *monodromy* of this family is the image of the monodromy representation
> $$\pi_1(S,t) \longrightarrow \operatorname{O}(H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})).$$
> By $\operatorname{Mon}(X)$ we denote the subgroup of $\operatorname{O}(H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}))$ generated by the monodromies of all possible families $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow S$ with central fiber $X \simeq \mathcal{X}_t$.

Now, I have never heard of monodromy representation and monodromy before, and I'm struggling looking for a reasonable reference to have the right definition/intuition in the setting I'm in.

First of all, what is the map $\pi_1(S,t) \longrightarrow \operatorname{O}(H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}))$?
Is there any good book/article to start with?

Comment: How much algebraic topology do you know?

Comment: I've seen monodromies be discussed in, for example, Lee's "introduction to topological manifolds".

Comment: I mean, do you know about fundamental groups, cohomology, Poincare duality? If you do, I can write an explanation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have a decent knowledge about the topics you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: @morrowmh thanks, I'll take a look